# How to set default dependent props when using destructuring assignment?

Tags: reactjs, object, destructuring, object-destructuring

Destructuring assignment is a well known method for assigning default props to React components:

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  onClick: () => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  getTextColor?: (theme: Theme) => string;
}

const Button = ({
  onClick,
  disabled = false,
  getTextColor = (theme) => theme.primary
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const computedTextColor = getTextColor(theme);
  // Rest of logic
}
```

Suppose now that I want the `getTextColor` prop to depend on the disabled prop:

```js
// OPTION 1 (without changing getTextColor type)

const Button = ({
  onClick,
  disabled = false,
  getTextColor = (theme) => disabled ? 'gray' : theme.primary
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const computedTextColor = getTextColor(theme);
  // Rest of logic
}
```

```js
// OPTION 2 (change getTextColor to (theme: Theme, disabled: boolean) => void)

const Button = ({
  onClick,
  disabled = false,
  getTextColor = (theme, buttonDisabled) => buttonDisabled ? 'gray' : theme.primary
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const computedTextColor = getTextColor(theme, disabled);
  // Rest of logic
}
```

Which of these two options is the "correct" way to achieve this sort of behavior OR is there a better way?